# How to remove second half of text inside of each option tag?

Tags: php, html, substring, preg-replace

I'm working with `file_get_contents()` and I get some html strings structured like this:

```
$html = "
<select>
   <option>I need this part 1/ I don't need this 1 </option>
   <option>I need this part 2/ I don't need this 2 </option>
   <option>I need this part 3/ I don't need this 3 </option>
   ...
   <option>I need this part 50/ I don't need this 50 </option>
</select>";
```

I want to get rid of all `/ I don't need this [n]`.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Your question or better task is unclear. Please be more precise in what result you are actually interested in. So how _exactly_ it is defined what section of markup should be kept and what should be dropped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Apart from that: please learn how this site works. SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help you with solving issues you run into when trying to solve your task yourself. For that you need to show the code you actually tried yourself. How else should we be able to help with that?

Answer (score 2):

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b56fe45b85e9b271ba20beaf344398af61f91894))

```
$html = "
<select>
   <option>I need this part 1/ I don't need this 1 </option>
   <option>I need this part 2/ I don't need this 2 </option>
   <option>I need this part 3/ I don't need this 3 </option>
   ...
   <option>I need this part 50/ I don't need this 50 </option>
</select>";

echo $html=preg_replace('~/.*<~','<',$html);
```

- Use `~` as the pattern delimiter so that you don't have to escape the slash inside your regular expression.
- The `.` <s>can</s> **should be greedy** because the dot won't go onto new lines unless you tell it to (by using an `s` flag at the end of the pattern) AND if any of your unwanted substrings contain a `<` this will protect your html text from being mangled.
- Don't use a capture group because it slows down your pattern and you aren't using any capture references in your replacement string.

Output:

```
<select>
   <option>I need this part 1</option>
   <option>I need this part 2</option>
   <option>I need this part 3</option>
   ...
   <option>I need this part 50</option>
</select>
```

---

Lastly, if your unwanted substrings don't contain a `<`, then the following pattern & replacement text will far outperform my above method:

Pattern: `~/[^<]+</~`
Replace: `</`
[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eqaq1i/1)